# Matlab precion when specifying fractions

Tags: matlab

I wanted to create a vector with three values 1/6, 2/3 and 1/6. Obviously I Matlab has to convert these rational numbers into real numbers but I expected that it would maximize the precision available.

It's storing the values as doubles but it's storing them as -

```
b =

    0.1667    0.6667    0.1667
```

This is a huge loss of precision. Isn't double supposed to mean 52 bits of accuracy for the fractional part of the number, why are the numbers truncated so severly?

Comment: what is the purpose of this scenario ? so that i can suggest possible solution

Comment: I am solving differential equations using Runge Kutta 4. The loss of precision is horrendous for numerical analysis such as this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The numbers are only displayed that way. Internally, they use full precision. You can use the `format` command to change display precision. For example:

```
format long
```

will display them as:

```
0.166666666666667    0.666666666666667    0.166666666666667
```

So the answer is simple; there is no loss of precision. It's only a display issue.

You can read the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html) on what other formats you can use to display numbers.

Answer (score 0):

you can not store values as 1/2 or 1/4 or 1/6 in to a Double variable... these are stored as decimals behind the system;  if you want to store these values , try storing it as string that would work;

Whenever you want to make mathematical calculation using these strings then convert the value into number and continue....

Comment: I don't see the point. That way, you would convert the same string over and over again, and always get the same answer. That wouldn't serve any purpose.

Comment: what is the purpose of this scenario ? so that i can suggest possible solution...

Comment: There's no scenario, really. The OP is just confused about the way Matlab displays numbers and thinks that the display precision represents the actual precision used to store the numbers.